# Join 2 tables and get the latest record

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables table1 contains the columns of id, status,created_by,created_date,name and table2 is a log table which contains id, updated_by,updated_date. Table2 contains multiple records of same id. I'm trying to get the resultant query which support to get the selected columns from both tables by join operation. but when I tried i'm getting the duplicate records associated with that id. I want only one latest record for that id. My query...

```
select  t.created_by,t.created_date,tl.updated_by,tl.updated_date
    from  test_name t
    join (
        SELECT  updated_by,updated_date,id
            from  test_log
            order by  updated_date desc
            limit  1
         ) tl  ON t.id=tl.id
    where  state = 'active';
```

Answer (score 4):

You could return the sequential number of a row within a partition (in this case `id`) of a result set, starting at 1 (`AND seqnum = 1`) for the first row in each partition.

See below

```
SELECT t.created_by, 
       t.created_date, 
       tl.updated_by, 
       tl.updated_date 
FROM   test_name t 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT tl.*,
            Row_number() 
              OVER ( 
                partition BY id 
                ORDER BY updated_date DESC ) AS seqnum 
             FROM   test_log tl) tl 
         ON t.id = tl.id 
            AND seqnum = 1 
WHERE  state = 'active';
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @AndriyM Let's hope the asker clears up the ambiguity in the tagging.

Comment: I found this by searching for it, and I'm using SQL Server. This worked brilliantly! Can't say I fully understand it right now, but it works! So I'm happy :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self join on log table to get to he latest row per table 1 something like:

```
select
    t.created_by,
    t.created_date,
    l1.updated_by,
    l1.updated_date 
from
    test_name t 
    left join test_log l1 
        on t.id = l1.id 
    left join test_log l2 
        on l1.id = l2.id 
        and l1.updated_date < l2.updated_date 
where
    t.state = 'active' 
    and l2.id is null ;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max discusses how to deal with dups when doing "groupwise max".

Answer (score 0):

If you create your table structure as below then you get perfect result using following query.

table1 contains columns like
pk_id_table1,
status,
created_by,
created_date,
name

table2 contains columns like
pk_id_table2,
pk_id_table1,
updated_by,
updated_date

```
SELECT table2.*, table1.name 
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.pk_id_table1=table1.pk_id_table1  
WHERE table2.pk_id_table2 
  IN (SELECT max(pk_id_table2) 
  FROM table2 
  GROUP BY pk_id_table1) 
ORDER BY pk_id_table2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RowNum,
            username,
            p.purchased,
            p.product_id
                FROM (
                    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  users.id) AS RowNum, users.id AS uid,username
                    FROM users
                ) AS users1
                LEFT JOIN  (SELECT orders.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by user_id  ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS seqnum
                FROM orders) p ON uid = p.user_id  AND p.seqnum = 1
            WHERE RowNum >= 0 AND uid ='111'
            ORDER BY RowNum
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the latest records from `log` for each `name` then this can't be performed by queries only in an easy way (at least within MySQL dialect). The simplest way is to create the copy of the `log` table `log_last` but with UNIQUE index on the `id` and `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax. Each record written into the `log` should be written into `log_last` too. IODKU ensure that old data will be overwritten by new ones and when you `SELECT * FROM log_last` you'll get all and only latest log lines for each `id`.

Comment: Perhaps it's not crystal clear from the description but my reading is they want latest record *per ID*, so `LIMIT 1` might not work

Comment: Seems to me TS also confuse "duplicates" with "multiple rows"